# Shrinkable header

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a sample directive where is the header shrinks when the user scrolls up... however when scrolling down the header does not appear until it reaches the top.... How to improve the code when scrolling down some distance, the header should appear.

.ts:

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
  @Directive({
    selector: '[header-shrink]',
    host: {
      '(ionScroll)': 'onContentScroll($event)'
    }
  })
  export class HeaderShrink {
    header: any;
    headerHeight: any;
    translateAmt: any;

   constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) { }

   ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.header = document.getElementsByClassName("shrinkable")[0];
    this.headerHeight = this.header.clientHeight;
   }

  onContentScroll(ev) {
   ev.domWrite(() => {
    this.updateHeader(ev);
    });
  }

 updateHeader(ev) {

   if (ev.scrollTop >= 0) {
    this.translateAmt = -ev.scrollTop / 4;

    } else {
      this.translateAmt =ev.scrollTop / 4;
  }

  this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'webkitTransform',   'translate3d(0,' + this.translateAmt + 'px,0)');
 }
}
```

.html:

```
 <ion-header class="shrinkable">
   <ion-navbar>
     <button ion-button menuToggle>
       <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
     </button>
  <ion-title>
    Jobs
  </ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
     <button ion-button end icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)">
     <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
     </button>
  </ion-buttons>
```

the directive is not perfect..Also how can I add a gradual item fading when the header is shrinking I want it to have a fading effect as well, it would be great if someone can show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better solution:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Directive({
  selector: '[header-shrink]',
  host: {
   '(ionScroll)': 'onContentScroll($event)'
  }
})
export class HeaderShrink {
  header: any;
  headerHeight: any;
  translateAmt: any;
  scrollPosition: number = 0;
  lastScrollTop: number = 0;

  activePage: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {

     this.activePage = this.navCtrl.getActive()._cmp;  // get current active page
      // ion-header classname
     this.header = this.activePage._nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("shrinkable")[0];

     // the height of the header
     this.headerHeight = this.header.clientHeight;
   }

   onContentScroll(ev) {
      ev.domWrite(() => {
          this.updateHeader(ev);
      });   
   }

   updateHeader(ev) {

     this.scrollPosition = ev.scrollTop;

     if (this.scrollPosition > this.lastScrollTop && this.scrollPosition >= 25) {
     // scrolling down
     this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'transition', 'all 0.3s linear');
     this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'transform', 'translateY(-' + this.headerHeight + 'px)');
     } else {
    // scrolling up
     this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'transform', 'translateY(0px)');
     }

    // reset
    this.lastScrollTop = this.scrollPosition;
   }
}
```

the code line for `activePage` because when adding the directive onto more than one component/page , it didn't function and the reason I quote 'probably cuz of multiple header in the DOM`... I am open to any suggestions upon improving this code.

this answer was taken from : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/shrinkable-header/78386/7

Answer (score 0):

```
        import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
      @Directive({
        selector: '[header-shrink]',
        host: {
          '(ionScroll)': 'onContentScroll($event)'
        }
      })
      export class HeaderShrink {
        header: any;
        headerHeight: any;
        translateAmt: any;
        lastScroll:number=0;
       constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) { }

       ngAfterViewInit() {

        this.header = document.getElementsByClassName("shrinkable")[0];
        this.headerHeight = this.header.clientHeight;
       }

      onContentScroll(ev) {
       ev.domWrite(() => {
        this.updateHeader(ev);
        });
      }

     updateHeader(ev) {

       if (ev.scrollTop >this.lastScrollTop) {
        this.translateAmt = -150;

        } else {
          this.translateAmt = 0;
      }

      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'webkitTransform',   'translate3d(0,' + this.translateAmt + 'px,0)');
this.lastScrollTop = ev.scrollTop;


     }
    }
```

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification